# kubectlはgcloudに付随してインストールされますか？

Tags: macos, google-cloud, homebrew, kubernetes

`kubernetes`のチュートリアルを読んでいたら、まだ`kubectl`をインストールしてないはずなのに既にインストールされていました。

```
$ kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"14", GitVersion:"v1.14.6", GitCommit:"96fac5cd13a5dc064f7d9f4f23030a6aeface6cc", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-08-19T11:13:49Z", GoVersion:"go1.12.9", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"darwin/amd64"}
The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
```

もしかしたらインストールだけして忘れてるのかもしれないのですがドキュメントには`brew`を使う方法が書いてあり、この`kubectl`は`brew`でインストールされてないのでそう判断しました。

```
$ brew list | grep kube
//出力なし
```

GCPは使ったことがあるので`gcloud`をインストールした時に一緒にインストールされたのだと考えたのですが、検索しても`gcloud`インストール時に別のコマンドもインストールされるかどうかの情報が見つかりませんでした。

この`kubectl`がどのようにインストールされたかを調べるにはどうすればよいでしょうか？ 以下が`gcloud`のバージョンです。

```
$ gcloud version
Google Cloud SDK 272.0.0
app-engine-go
app-engine-python 1.9.87
bq 2.0.50
cloud-datastore-emulator 2.1.0
core 2019.11.16
gcloud
gsutil 4.46
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/quickstart?hl=ja

このドキュメントによれば `gcloud` のインストール時ではなく、 `gcloud components install kubectl` コマンドで明示的にインストールしているように見えますが、正確なところは把握していません。

`which kubectl` コマンドの結果は参考になります。`kubectl` バイナリが `google-cloud-sdk` の下なら `gcloud` 経由でインストールしたもの、

```
$ which kubectl
/path/to/google-cloud-sdk/bin/kubectl
```

そうでなければ `brew` やマニュアルでダウンロードしたものと推測できます。

```
$ which kubectl
/usr/local/bin/kubectl
```

`brew` 経由なら `/usr/local/Cellar/.../bin/kubectl` へリンクされているかもしれません。

```
$ ls -l /usr/local/bin/kubectl
... /usr/local/bin/kubectl -> ../Cellar/kubernetes-cli/1.16.3/bin/kubectl
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。リンク先を見ると`/Applications/Docker.app/Contents/Resources/bin/kubectl`になっており、Dockerに付属するものでした。